# Is it possible to loop in PLSQL to retrieve several results from one table based on variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

To make my question clear I will give you an example of what I want to do in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter= 100
WHILE ( @Counter <= 105)

BEGIN
    
SELECT  *
    FROM employees e    
      where e.employee_id = @Counter

SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1

END
```

This will return several results (grids) in SQL Server, I would like to recreate this in PLSQL but couldn't find any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with n (counter) as (
      select 100 as counter
      from dual
      union all
      select counter + 1
      from n
      where counter < 105
     )
select e.*
from employees e join
     n
     on e.employee_id = n.counter;
```

You can do something quite similar in SQL Server.  There is no need for a loop in either database.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive query works, but seems like a little over kill. How about a single simple select:

```
select e.*
from employees e 
where e.employee_id between 100 and 105;
```

Comment: Yeah you can do the stated problem with a single select but I just pointed out the easy query on sample database, rather than complex one with my own database :)